# How to format a date (randomly generated within a period) to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, date

I am using below function to get randomize date.
I am getting date in MM/DD/YYYY format ,
Can anyone help me in how can i get date in DD/MM/YYYY format.

```js
function randomDate(date1, date2) {
  function randomValueBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }
  var date1 = date1 || '01-01-1970'
  var date2 = date2 || new Date().toLocaleDateString()
  date1 = new Date(date1).getTime()
  date2 = new Date(date2).getTime()
  if (date1 > date2) {
    return new Date(randomValueBetween(date2, date1)).toLocaleDateString()
  } else {
    return new Date(randomValueBetween(date1, date2)).toLocaleDateString()

  }
}
var date = randomDate('02/13/2020', '01/01/2018');

console.log(date)
```

Comment: Why use `toLocaleDateString` if you don't want a local specific format? [MDN toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Also, you want the return format to not match the input format? (`02/13/2020`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split on / and recontrsuct. Try like:

```js
var oldDate = '02/13/2020';

function formatDate (date){
  var splittedDate = date.split('/');
  return splittedDate[1]+'/'+ splittedDate[0]+'/'+splittedDate[2];
}

console.log(formatDate(oldDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just force a European locale

```js
const randomValueBetween = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

function randomDate(date1, date2) {
  var date1 = date1 || '01-01-1970';
  var date2 = date2 || new Date();
  date1 = new Date(date1).getTime();
  date2 = new Date(date2).getTime();
  return date1 > date2 ? new Date(randomValueBetween(date2, date1)).toLocaleDateString("dk-DK") :
                         new Date(randomValueBetween(date1, date2)).toLocaleDateString("dk-DK")
}
var date = randomDate('02/13/2020', '01/01/2018');
console.log(date)
date = randomDate('02/13/2020');
console.log(date)
date = randomDate();
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's more flexible to code by reserving the feature-rich [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object until the last moment. Also [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) behaves differently in different browser locale environment. The string is not always what you might expect.

```js
function randomDate(date1, date2) {
  function randomValueBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }
  var date1 = date1 || '01-01-1970'
  var date2 = date2 || new Date().toLocaleDateString()
  date1 = new Date(date1).getTime()
  date2 = new Date(date2).getTime()

  // Note: modify the function to return Date instead of string
  if (date1 > date2) {
    return new Date(randomValueBetween(date2, date1));
  } else {
    return new Date(randomValueBetween(date1, date2));
  }
}

// with javascript's Date as input, you can freely reformat
// the output with Date.prototype.* methods.
function formatDate(date) {
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1 + "";
  let day = date.getDate() + "";
  return day.padStart(2, "0") + "/" + month.padStart(2, "0") + "/" + year;
}

var date = formatDate(randomDate('02/13/2020', '01/01/2018'));
console.log(date)
```